# Failed to resolve component 'esp_ipc'

Tags: cmake, arduino, esp32, platformio, esp-idf

I am configuring a project on an ESP32doitdev board. I am using the native esp32-framework as well as arduino. I am working with the platformio core in order to compile. I am getting an error which resolves to a inter-processor call module in the esp32-idf framework. In trying to fix the issue on my own I went into `idf.py menuconfig` and tried to configure anything that would logically relate to an inter-processor call module. However, I was unsuccessful. I was wondering if someone could give me some insight into why this error might be happening? I am relatively new to cmake and I'm a bit lost.

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(Peripherals)
```

#### ESP-IDF Inter Processor Call Configuration

![enter image description here][1]

#### Build Error Message `pio run`

```
francis@eniac:~/Documents/Peripheral$ /home/francis/.platformio/penv/bin/pio  run
Processing esp32doit-devkit-v1 (platform: espressif32; board: esp32doit-devkit-v1; framework: espidf, arduino)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32doit-devkit-v1.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (3.3.2) > DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (esp-prog) External (esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES: 
 - framework-arduinoespressif32 0.0.0+sha.a418058 
 - framework-espidf 3.40001.200521 (4.0.1) 
 - tool-cmake 3.16.4 
 - tool-esptoolpy 1.30100.210531 (3.1.0) 
 - tool-ninja 1.7.1 
 - toolchain-esp32ulp 1.22851.191205 (2.28.51) 
 - toolchain-xtensa32 2.80400.210211 (8.4.0)
Installing ESP-IDF's Python dependencies
Collecting cryptography>=2.1.4
  Using cached cryptography-35.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (3.5 MB)
Collecting future>=0.15.2
  Using cached future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing<2.4.0,>=2.0.3
  Using cached pyparsing-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting kconfiglib==13.7.1
  Using cached kconfiglib-13.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (446 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, pyparsing, kconfiglib, future, cryptography
Successfully installed cffi-1.15.0 cryptography-35.0.0 future-0.18.2 kconfiglib-13.7.1 pycparser-2.20 pyparsing-2.3.1
Warning! Arduino framework as an ESP-IDF component doesn't handle the `variant` field! The default `esp32` variant will be used.
Reading CMake configuration...
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.25.1") 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /home/francis/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/francis/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/francis/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/francis/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/francis/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Project version: 7bca477-dirty
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/francis/Documents/Peripheral/.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
CMake Error at /home/francis/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:185 (message):
  Failed to resolve component 'esp_ipc'.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/francis/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:216 (__build_resolve_and_add_req)
  /home/francis/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/build.cmake:425 (__build_expand_requirements)
  /home/francis/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:348 (idf_build_process)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

#### platform.ini

```
[env:esp32doit-devkit-v1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32doit-devkit-v1
framework = espidf, arduino
platform_packages = framework-arduinoespressif32 @ https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32.git
monitor_speed = 115200
build_flags = 
    -D ARDUINO=100 
    -D ESP32=100
    -I src/lib/*/src/*
```

Comment: The **first error message** you got is `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)`. So you need try to debug exactly that error. Every other error you got is secondary: it could be that other error are result of the first one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what directory needs to be a git repository as the main project is a git repository and has access to a `.git` folder?

Comment: BTW, the message `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!` is emitted by CMake and means that some error has been occurred **before**. So corresponding error message is **above** the lines you show in your question post.

Comment: I apologize for providing incomplete information. I have updated my original post to reflect the entirety of the compiler message I am working with.